# Why is the call to super() not using __getattr__ in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, inheritance

So I have a composition in which why my wrapper class contains a Pandas DataFrame. Because I want to add some behaviors to it, I've setup the following:

```
class DataFrameWrapper(dict):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, *args, **kwargs):
        self.df = dataframe
        self.pandas_callables = [method_name for method_name in dir(self.df)
                                    if callable(getattr(self.df, method_name))]
        super(DataFrameWrapper, self).__init__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.df[item]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.pandas_callables:
            # this is a dataframe method call - forward to the dataframe & return that
            return object.__getattribute__(self.df, item)
        else:
            try:  # try to return our own attribute, if any
                return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
            except AttributeError as ex:
                # likely a panda attribute. IF not, then it's a genuine attribute
                # error, so we don't catch it and let it raise another exception
                return object.__getattribute__(self.df, item)
```

Then I have say

```
class Foo(DataFrameWrapper):
    def __init__(self, dataframe,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(dataframe,  *args, **kwargs)

class Bar(Foo)
    """ concrete implementation class """

class Baz(Foo)
    """ concrete implementation class """
```

So that we can do:

```
bar = Bar(df)
bar.to_json()
bar.some_custom_method()
col = bar["column_name"]
```

Now, if I do say:

```
json = bar.to_json()
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to add additional processing in Foo, so I want to do:

```
class Foo(DataFrameWrapper):
   def to_json(*args, **kwrags)
      # do additional stuff
      super().to_json(*args, **kwrags)
```

However in that case, `__getattr__()` is never called in the wrapper and I just get

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

Why?

EDIT:

If I do something dumb, like this:

```
class DataFrameWrapper(dict):

    ### previous code unchanged ###

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == "to_json":
            return object.__getattr__(self, item)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
```

Then the call to to_json() works. [According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), I would expect what hack I just did to be what *should* happen anyways.

Comment: [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) isn't a method of anything you've defined, so why would it be affected?

Comment: Well, I'm expecting that super() will call DataFrameWrapper.__getattribute__("to_json"), which it does. It fails and raises AttributeError, because  to_json isn't an attribute of DataFrameWrapper. I would then expect DataFrameWrapper.__getattr__("to_json") to be called, but it isn't. Hence my implementation never tries to find the method within the panda_callables, and just raise the AttributeError and crashes instead.

Comment: The linked documentation says "Note that `super()` is implemented as part of the binding process for explicit dotted attribute lookups such as `super().__getitem__(name)`. It does so by implementing its own `__getattribute__()` method for searching classes in a predictable order that supports cooperative multiple inheritance." I.E. Nothing you've done is affect that.

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes okay, right. The edit I just made above in trying to debug this makes more sense now - super().__getattribute__(). But even then, I don't think I understand why this doesn't work. Shouldn't the __mro__ still be followed, my wrapper's __getattribute__ still be called (it's in the mro after all!) and then that should also raise AttributeError, thus calling my wrapper's __getattr__?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, taking a stab at an attempt of an answer, based on @martineau comments above.

So yes, `super()` is actually not simply calling the parent's methods directly. Because Python supports multiple inheritance, a call to `super().foo()` must do a bit more than just calling the (first) parent class' `__getattribute__`. It has to establish some mechanism to ensure that python's implementation of multiple inheritance is coherent.

That being, if I call the parent's method directly (old-school according to [Python super()'s guide](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)), then it works as I expected initially:

```
class Foo(DataFrameWrapper):
    def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        return DataFrameWrapper.__getattr__(self, "to_json")(*args, **kwargs)
```

That "solves" the issue in the sense that I get the functionality expected.

Now to understand WHY super() didn't work:

`super` has a `__getattribute__` method, but *not* a `__getattr__` method. Thus I am guessing that what happens might be along the lines of:

1. `super().__getattribute__("to_json")` is called
2. `super` goes through the MRO to try to find the attribute
3. According to comments below, it looks into each classe's dict for the attribute it's looking for. Guessing it doesn't actually call each classe's **getattribute** methods for efficiency reason.
4. See comments below for example details. Maybe eventually I'll structure that into the answer.

Comment: `super` completely ignores all `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` overrides when performing its lookup. It has its own lookup logic and doesn't care about yours.

Comment: Yeah that's the understanding I'm coming to right now. Although to be precise, it doesn't seem to implement a __getattr__. At least dir(super) says it doesn't.

Comment: So I guess I'll be able to accept my own answer. Geez, all that work just to come to the conclusion that I shouldn't use super in that case. And also a better graps of python's inner mechanism too I guess. Just feel a little disappointing to spend like 2 hours on that.... yup, found another rabbit hole!

Comment: Item 3 in your list is wrong. It's not triggering each class's `__getattribute__`. It doesn't care about those methods.

Comment: Yes it does - see the edit in my question above. It doesn't call getattr, but it does call each classe's getattribute. It DOES need to know if the classes in the mro do have the attribute requested, and how would it do that without calling their getattribute?

Comment: It ignores `__getattribute__`. See [here](https://ideone.com/Xphy9C), for example. The `calling getattribute for method` line comes from the original `Bar().method` lookup in the example. There's no second print output for the lookup in `super().method()`. There would be a second print output if the `super().method()` lookup called `Foo.__getattribute__`.

Comment: `super` finds attributes by directly looking in the dict of each class it searches, and handling descriptors manually.

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/MFhyz3) an example with the method names adjusted for clarity. In this example, it's easier to see that `Foo.__getattribute__` is only triggered for the `Bar().method2()` lookup, not the `super().method()` lookup.

Comment: Jeez, you're right. Well I'm just going to edit my "answer" and point to this discussion. I'm happy I learned those things but I just don't want to hear/write anything else about for a little while. Thanks for the details. Go Monica!